# "Error validating Name:Invalid string." When Adding Customer

Tags: syntax-error, intuit-partner-platform, quickbooks-online

I receive this error when adding a QBO Customer with a name that has greater/less than characters ('>', '<'). I've looked through the documentation and can't find a lit of unacceptable characters. How do I know what is and is not acceptable? I just need to know what to look for to sanitize our local data before uploading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The API is XML-based, right?  That means you need to either escape the characters into "&gt;" and "&lt;" respectively, probably with a standard library available in your environment; or filter [the 5 characters listed here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1091953).

Comment: I'd assume their API would do the escaping during serialization. Besides, there are other characters that their API doesn't like such as a colon (:). It'd be nice if there was documentation that listed their own particular character quirks.

Comment: Yeah, if you're using an official wrapper API from them, I would think it would escape, so maybe that's not really the issue.  Sounds like they are just picky about what characters they allow.